# How to define multiple resource groups and azure VM names in single varialble

Tags: azure, powershell

I am preparing PowerShell script to disable auto-shutdown option for all azure VMs in multiple resource groups. As of now I have prepare the script to disable auto shutdown option for a single resource group and single VM. But I need to define multiple resource group names and multiple VM names in single variable. Can you please help me with this issue.

Below is the PowerShell script:

```
Connect-AzAccount
$resourcegroup = "RG-Test1"
$vm = "devvm1"
$shutdown_time = "0000"
$shutdown_timezone = "India Standard Time"
$properties = @{
    "status" = "Disabled";
    "taskType" = "ComputeVmShutdownTask";
    "dailyRecurrence" = @{"time" = $shutdown_time };
    "timeZoneId" = $shutdown_timezone;
    "notificationSettings" = @{
        "status" = "Disabled";
        "timeInMinutes" = 00
    }
    "targetResourceId" = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Name $vm).Id
}
New-AzResource -ResourceId ("/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-{2}" -f (Get-AzContext).Subscription.Id, $resourcegroup, $vm) -Location (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Name $vm).Location -Properties $properties -Force
```

Comment: I am trying to add a variable by defining multiple resource group names and VM names
$resourcegroup = 'RG-Test1', 'RG-Test2'
$vm = 'devvm1', 'DevVm2'
But it is giving error like below:
Get-AzVM : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ResourceGroupName'. Specified method is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

To disable auto-shutdown option for all azure VMs in multiple resource groups, make use of below code.

```
# Define an array of resource group names
$resourcegroups = @("RG1",  "RG2")

# Define an array of VM names
$vms = @("vm1", "vm2")

$shutdown_time = "0000"
$shutdown_timezone = "India Standard Time"

# Loop through resource groups and VMs
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $resourcegroups.Length; $i++) {
    $resourcegroup = $resourcegroups[$i]
    $vm = $vms[$i]

    $properties = @{
        "status" = "Disabled"
        "taskType" = "ComputeVmShutdownTask"
        "dailyRecurrence" = @{"time" = $shutdown_time }
        "timeZoneId" = $shutdown_timezone
        "notificationSettings" = @{
            "status" = "Disabled"
            "timeInMinutes" = 00
        }
        "targetResourceId" = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Name $vm).Id
    }

    New-AzResource -ResourceId ("/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-{2}" -f (Get-AzContext).Subscription.Id, $resourcegroup, $vm) -Location (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Name $vm).Location -Properties $properties -Force
}
```

**Output:**

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/0LM1cH3.png)]

When I checked the same in portal it disabled auto-shutdown for multiple vm's and resource group like below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Imran. Thanks for the quick solution. Issue is fixed now.

Comment: Hi Imran. I have one more query regarding the same PowerShell script. I need to get the VM details automatically by defining only resource groups instead of defining VM names. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: sure, your query is different from Qs asked here. Raise a new Question and community will address that.

Comment: Hi Imran. I have raised new question regarding the same.